# PHP Cron Job Backup

Tags: php, cron, filesize

I have a cron job script that is done, and just fine tuning some parts of it.

```
$archive_loc = $temp_dir . '/files.tar';
exec("tar cf " . $archive_loc . " " . $files_dir);
$compressed_file = $prefix . "_backup_" . time() . '.tar.gz';
$compressed_loc = $backup_loc . "/" . $compressed_file;
exec ("tar -zcvf " . $compressed_loc . " " . $temp_dir);
```

The cron job has its own email, that sends us a 'job complete' type message - however, I wanted to get the filesize of the backup .tar.gz emailed to us.

I have tried

```
$sizeofbackup = filesize($archive_loc);
and 
$sizeofbackup2 = filesize($compressed_loc);
```

But both of these do not return any value within the email.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the content of `$archive_loc` and `$compressed_loc`? It sounds like folders. Use the path to the generated backup file instead of the folder they're in.

Comment: are `$temp_dir` and `$backup_loc` and `$prefix` defined? If not, you're trying to create those tar/tgz files in the root of your file system, which will almost certainly fail with a permission denied (unless you're running this as root).

Comment: yes, $temp_dir and $backup_loc are defined. the $archive_loc is the file of part of the backup, the $compress_file is the main file and the $compressed_loc is the file path to the compressed file. So, should I be using filesize($compress_file) ?